# How to update smalldatetime field with only current date(without current time) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have added a new column `[PriceStartOn]` of type `smalldatetime` to a table with existing data. Now I want to fill the column with the current date.

I used the `GETDATE()` function but it also add the current time.

The final result should be like this

```
2014-07-24 00:00:00
```

I searched the web and couldn’t find any sample on this. Based on other answers, I tried following code, it shows the correct format but the date was wrong, it returned `1905-08-08 00:00:00`

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME 
SET @date = GETDATE()   

UPDATE Product
SET [PriceStartOn] = ('' + DATEPART( year, @date ) + '-' + DATEPART( MONTH, @date) + '-'  +  DATEPART( DAY, @date) + '')
WHERE [PriceStartOn]IS NULL;
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast the `datetime` to `date`:

```
UPDATE Product
   SET PriceStartOn = cast(@date as date)
   WHERE PriceStartOn IS NULL;
```

You don't actually need a variable for this, you can do this directly on the function:

```
UPDATE Product
   SET PriceStartOn = cast(getdate() as date)
   WHERE PriceStartOn IS NULL;
```